# node.js request stuck in middleware function (authentication)?

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, jwt, middleware

I am building a node.js server to handle logins and actions in my iOS app. One of the functions I wrote is checkAuth, which is middleware for most of my requests to check if a user is authenticated and has permission to do what he wants to do.

Now I am facing a problem where sometimes, but not always, the middleware function (checkAuth) is stuck. I receive logs from this function in my console, but nothing from the request (which should happen after authentication is successful).

This is the function I currently wrote. It is not optimized yet as I am testing everything, but it should do what I want it to do (and it does, most of the time):

```
const saltRounds = process.env.JWT_ROUNDS
const secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET
const checkRefreshTime = 10 // set to 10 seconds for testing, will increase later

function checkAuth(req, res, next) {
    var token = req.headers['x-access-token']
    jwt.verify(token, secret, (error, decoded) => {
        console.log("checking auth")
        if(error) {
            console.log(error)
            res.json({ errorCode: 406 })
        } else {
            const decoded = jwt.verify(token, secret)
            var checkTime = (Date.now() / 1000) - checkRefreshTime;
            if (decoded.iat < checkTime) {
                console.log("DEC:", decoded)
                const userID = decoded.userID
                const queryString = "SELECT userRefreshToken, userName, userDisplayName, userProfilePicURL, userDOB, userGender FROM users WHERE userID = ? LIMIT 1"
                pool.getConnection(function(error, connection) {
                    if(error) {
                        console.log(error)
                        res.json({ errorCode: 500 })
                    }
                    connection.query(queryString, [userID], (error, selectRows, fields) => {
                        if(error) {
                            console.log(error)
                            res.json({ errorCode: 500 })
                        }
                        if(selectRows.length > 0) {
                            if(selectRows[0].userRefreshToken == decoded.userRefreshToken) {
                                var userAge = moment().diff(selectRows[0].userDOB, 'years');
                                const payload = {
                                    userID: userID,
                                    userName: selectRows[0].userName,
                                    userDisplayName: selectRows[0].userDisplayName,
                                    userProfilePicURL: selectRows[0].userProfilePicURL,
                                    userRefreshToken: selectRows[0].userRefreshToken,
                                    userAge: userAge,
                                    userGender: selectRows[0].userGender
                                }
                                var newToken = jwt.sign(payload, secret, { expiresIn: '21d' });
                                console.log("new token sent ", newToken)
                                res.locals.authToken = newToken
                                console.log("moving to next")
                                return next()
                            } else {
                                console.log("wrong refresh token")
                                res.json({ errorCode: 405, authResult: false })
                            }
                        } else {
                            console.log("0 results found!")
                            res.json({ errorCode: 503, authResult: false })
                        }
                        connection.release()
                    })
                })
            } else {
                console.log("moving to next 2")
                return next()
            }
        }
    })
}
```

It probably isn't the most beautiful code you have ever seen. That's not my issue at this moment - I will optimize at a later time. Right now I am concerned about the fact that sometimes the function is stuck after the second check. The last output I then receive is "DEC: " followed by the decoded token in my console (line 16).

Other useful information: I run my server on an Ubuntu 18.04 server from DigitalOcean and use forever to keep it running:
`forever start --minUptime 1000 --spinSleepTime 1000 server.js`

Anybody who knows why this is happening?

EDIT: as per comment, the definition of `pool`

```
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 100,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    database: process.env.DB_BASE,
    ssl      : {
          ca   : fs.readFileSync('***********'),
          key  : fs.readFileSync('*********'),
          cert : fs.readFileSync('********'),
    },
    charset : 'utf8mb4',
    dateStrings: true
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see where `pool` is defined anywhere. That could be throwing an error in the server logs.

Put a console log in the connection function to check that it actually connected to mySQL since that is the next function in the chain.

Comment: Excuse me. Looked over that as pool is defined on top of the document and used along different requests. Should I declare it in each request separately? Also, added the definition of pool to my OP.

Comment: It just wasn't defined in the code example, so I couldn't really replicate the problem. When you check in the server logs, is anything popping up?

Comment: No - just that it stops logging after DEC: //decoded value. I'm also stuck - hence the question. So I'm wondering if it could have something to do with the server, or with forever (which is why I included those details). I'm running the smallest DigitalOcean droplet as I'm still in development, so I could be out of memory maybe? I'm running two servers (one for node.js, one for mySQL) on 1 GB memory, 1 vCPU, 25 gb disk space and 1 tb transfer. disk space and transfer are fine, memory and cpu are nowhere near the max.. so I don't know.

Comment: Maybe put a console log in the connection function to check that it actually connected to mySQL since that is the next function in the chain.

Comment: Hmm could be indeed. Will try that and see what comes out when it happens again. Also, by restarting the node.js file (forever restart), the problem resolves, which could indicate the connection indeed times out or something? Does this happen in node.js? - thank you so far, by the way

Comment: Good question. I am not sure with mySQL how that works. With MongoDB, you use one connection and then keep reusing that single connection everywhere in your code. You would include logic to say if you can't get that connection, reconnect and store the new connection.

Comment: Eventually figured it out by checking out my MySQL connections. I allow 100 connections in the pool, but didn't release them correctly. I now release the connection right after the query and this seems to resolve the problem. Thanks Nick, for the heads up it might have something to do with the MySQL connection.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out. I'll update the answer for you if you want to accept it.